# How to print child tag name of select parent tag using Single Java Method?

Tags: java, xml

I need to print Child tag name of select parent tag using Java Method. In this given below Xml File. I am going select a parent tag **subject** and I am going to print each and every child and SubChild Tag inside subject parent tag.Example: div,p,LiberaryBook,p,p,textfile,textfile,textfile. 2. And it should print the text inside p tag which contain textfile tag
1. How to print the child tag name from select parent tag? and print the How to print text inside p tag which contain textfile tag?

```
<parent>
<Body class="student" id="181_student_method_3">
<Book class="Book_In_School_11" id="181_student_method_11"/>
<subject class="subject_information " id="181_student_subject_12"/>
<div class="div_passage " id="181_div_method_3">
<p class=" p_book_name" id="181_paragraph_13">
Best Java
<LiberaryBook class="Liberary" id="181_Liberary_9" >
<span class="p_span_name" id="181_span_13">Hello</span>
</LiberaryBook>
Java Program
</p>
<p class=" p_book_name" id="181_paragraph_13">
World
</p>
<p class="p_book_name" id="181_paragraph_14">
<textfile class="choice" id="C_10">Java.</textfile>
<textfile class="choice" id="C_11">
Find out how you rate against top coders.
</textfile>
<textfile class="choice3 " id="choice_12">
Unlock awesome startup jobs and hacker deals.
</textfile>
<textfile class="choice4 " id="choice_13">
User Id friends.
</textfile>
</p>
</div>
</subject>
</Body>
</parent>
```

```html
 private static void deleteElement(Document someNode) {
    NodeList parentNode = someNode.getElementsByTagName("hottextInteraction").item(0).getChildNodes();
    int parentNodeContentSize = parentNode.getLength();
    for (int i = 0; i < parentNodeContentSize; i++) {
        Node parentNodeitem = parentNode.item(i);
        System.out.println("ChildList"+((Node) parentNodeitem.getChildNodes()).getNodeName());
            NamedNodeMap attributes = parentNodeitem.getAttributes();
            String attributeInParent = attributes != null ? (attributes
                    .getNamedItem("class") != null ? attributes.getNamedItem(
                    "class").getNodeValue().trim() : null) : null;

            if (attributeInParent != null && attributeInParent.equals("div_passage")) {
                NodeList stemContent = parentNodeitem.getChildNodes();

                for(int j=0;j<stemContent.getLength();j++){
                    Node stem = stemContent.item(j);

                    if(stem instanceof Element && (stem.getNodeName().equals("p"))){
                        NodeList parentNode1 = someNode.getElementsByTagName("p");//First try.item(0).getChildNodes();
                        int parentNodeContentSize1 = parentNode1.getLength();
                        System.out.println(parentNodeContentSize1);
                        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < parentNodeContentSize1;) {

                        Node node = parentNode1.item(i1);
                        if (node instanceof Element) {
                            Element childElement = (Element) node;
                            System.out.println("tag name: " + childElement.getTagName());
                        }i1++;

                        System.out.println("Sub Child Tag:"+node.getFirstChild().getNodeName());*/
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

}
}
```

Comment: And whats the question ?? What is the problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: You can now check with the question.

Comment: So in this case if input tag name is subject then whats the output?

Comment: The output will be the child tag name and print text content only from inside pTag, But if the ptag contain textfile as subchild tag, code should not take that text...

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Check with this code to get Child Tag name and get it's text content inside P tag

package com.video.convertor;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
 import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
 import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
 import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
 import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
 import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
 import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

 import org.w3c.dom.Document;
 import org.w3c.dom.Element;
 import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
 import org.w3c.dom.Node;
 import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

 public class Hottext {



 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePath = "/Users/myXml/check/test.xml";
    File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    try {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        //Element root = doc.getDocumentElement(); 
        System.out.println(deleteElement(doc));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory =   TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/Users/myXml/DEMO4.xml"));
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        System.out.println("XML file updated successfully");

    } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException | TransformerException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String deleteElement(Document someNode) {
String contents = "";
NodeList itemBody =    someNode.getElementsByTagName("subject").item(0).getChildNodes();
int itemBodyContentSize = itemBody.getLength();
for (int i = 0; i < itemBodyContentSize; i++) {
Node passage = itemBody.item(i);
NamedNodeMap attributes = passage.getAttributes();
String selectText = attributes != null ? (attributes
        .getNamedItem("class") != null ? attributes.getNamedItem(
        "class").getNodeValue() : null) : null;
 if (selectText != null && selectText.toString().trim().equals("div_passage")) {
    NodeList pasageElements = passage.getChildNodes();
    int length = pasageElements.getLength();
    boolean isPassageContent = false;
    for(int j=0;j<length;j++){
        Node passageContent = pasageElements.item(j);
        if(passageContent instanceof Element && (passageContent.getNodeName().equals("p"))){
            if(isPassageContent){
                NodeList p = pasageElements.item(j).getChildNodes();                    
                for (int k = 0;k < p.getLength(); k++){
                    Node noded = p.item(k);
                    if (noded.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                         if(noded.getNodeName() != null && (noded.getNodeName().equals("textfile"))){
                             contents = contents+p.item(k).getTextContent()+"\n";
                         }
                 }
            }
       }else{
                isPassageContent = true;
            }
        }       

    }
}

}return contents;
}
}
```